# Remove all options in select but the first

Tags: jquery, html

I'm developing an `ASP.NET` `MVC 5` app with `C#` and `.NET Framework 4.7.`

I want to remove all the options in except but the first. This is the select:

```
<select data-productlistaction="/ProductionOrder/ProductionOrderData" id="ProductionOrderNameSelectId" name="ProductionOrders">
   <option value="">Production Orders</option>
   <option value="ProOrd_001">ProOrd_001</option>
</select>
```

This is the `cshtml` for the select:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "ProductionOrders",
    new SelectList(
        Model.Select(x => new { Value = x, Text = x }),
        "Value",
        "Text"
    ),
    @Resources.ProOrdOverviewDropDownLabel,
    new {
        id = "ProductionOrderNameSelectId",
        data_productlistaction = @Url.Action("ProductionOrderData") }
)
```

And this is the `jQuery` to remove all options but the first:

```
var selectList  = $("#ProductionOrderNameSelectId");
selectList('option:gt(0)').remove();
```

But when I do it, I get this select:

```
<select data-productlistaction="/ProductionOrder/ProductionOrderData" id="ProductionOrderNameSelectId" name="ProductionOrders">
   <option value="ProOrd_001">ProOrd_001</option>
</select>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var selectList  = $("#ProductionOrderNameSelectId");
selectList.find('option').not(':first').remove();
```

This will look for the options, and remove all except the first

Also not sure what you `target` refers to in `target.selectList('option:gt(0)').remove();`

```js
var selectList  = $("#ProductionOrderNameSelectId");
selectList.find('option').not(':first').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select data-productlistaction="/ProductionOrder/ProductionOrderData" id="ProductionOrderNameSelectId" name="ProductionOrders">
   <option value="">Production Orders</option>
   <option value="ProOrd_001">ProOrd_001</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I have tried to change `target` with `selectList` but I think I make a mix with the two names: `target.selectList`.

Comment: @VansFannel Ahh okay. anyway I hope it solved your problem

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
var selectList = $('#ProductionOrderNameSelectId');
selectList.find('option:gt(0)').remove();
```

Or you could:

```
selectList.find('option:not(:first-child)').remove();
```